# stdin.write() to cmd doesn't seem to be working. Any solutions to how to pass strings to command prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, stdin, popen

I have looked at a lot of answers to `stdin.write()` issues and none have helped. I am trying to have my code change the password for an account through cmd but this requires the program to submit the password twice after I run `mt =subprocess.Popen(["net","users", username, "*"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`.

```
pswd = 'password'
pswd = pswd.encode() + b'\n'
mt =subprocess.Popen(["net","users", username, "*"], stdout = 
subprocess.PIPE,stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

mt.stdin.flush()
mt.stdin.write(pswd)
mt.stdin.flush()
mt.stdin.write(pswd)

(out, er) = mt.communicate()

st = str(out)

print(st)
```

This is not the entire program but this is where the `stdin.write()` commands won't work. I have also tried `mt.communicate(pswd)` but that doesn't work either. The output is:

```
b'Type a password for the user: Retype the password to confirm: \r\n\r\n'
>>>
```

Basically... I just need a way to pass a string to cmd.

Comment: Do you have ever opened a command prompt window and executed `net user /?` to get output the help for command __NET__ for __USER__ actions? __Note:__ `user` (singular) and not `users` (plural) is the right first argument string. If the password is already hard coded in your Python script, why do you not run `net` with third argument being `pswd` instead of `"*"`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mofi! I have already tried this and in order to change the password like this the python script would need to run cmd as admin.